# Sending array of strings to web api using postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

Here is a screenshot of my postman screen where I am attempting to make a get request to a web api call.

[image: chrome postman get request]

I also tried to make the call using [] with no numbers for each parameter and this did not work either.  In both cases, the filenames array of string ended up being null.  Disregard the error at the bottom of the screen as I replaced the actual api call with a sample.  I saw the null value when I hit the breakpoint for the correct api call.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is the Controller Method defined?

Comment: Add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the `string[] filenames` parameter.

Comment: [HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test(string[] filenames)

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given your action:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test(string[] filenames) {
  // ...
}
```

You need to add a `[FromUri]` attribute to your `string[] filenames` parameter. The reason is documented [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Arrays are considered a complex type. The `[FromUri]` attribute will override the default behaviour and instruct Web API to try and bind this parameter from the URI.